# Is it possible to find out the current baud rate while sending data serially to a microcontroller using PySerial?

Tags: python, pyserial, uart, serial-communication

I'm trying to find a way to calculate the current baud rate while transmitting data serially to a microcontroller. I **don't** want to source this from the baud rate setting used by Python Serial module rather I want to find the start and end time of data transmission and use this to calculate the actual baud rate of transmission since I already know that the number of bits I'm transmitting per packet (1 start bit, 8 data bits, 1 stop bit).

Comment: This doesn't really make sense - what baud rate are you imagining might be in effect, other than the one that you specified when opening the port?  I don't see how you'd measure this accurately, anyway - your program is only putting bytes into a buffer (to be delivered by the hardware at its own rate), you can't tell exactly when any byte actually got transmitted.

Comment: Maybe the actual baud rate may or may not be exactly equal to the baud rate specified when opening the serial port? I was looking for a way to calculate the baud rate individually for a single transmission of 1 start bit, 8 data bits, 1 stop bit if there was a method to find the start and finish time of transmission.

Comment: The actual baud rate is *never* going to be exactly equal to the specified baud rate - and it doesn't need to be: there can be up to about 5% mismatch in baud rates before any problem appears.  Any PC serial port is going to be accurate to within a fraction of a percent - if there's any problem, it's likely to be at the other end (especially if your microcontroller uses an RC oscillator instead of a crystal or resonator for its timing).